# Replication rows from a column B to each category of a column in Table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

DBFiddle for the below question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85a9d26620bea264c26f5584c3302f40

This is the first table named sample:

[image]

This is the second table named company:

[image]

I want all the company *names* from table **company** for each *dat* in table **Sample**

I tried this:

```
`select a.Dat, a.cname, (case when a.name <> a.cname then 0 else a.cnt end) as c from 
(select s.*, c.name as cname from sample s
right join company c on c.name = s.name) a`
```

I get this:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

How to do this in MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select d.dat, c.name, coalesce(s.cnt, 0) as cnt
from (select distinct dat from sample) d cross join 
 company c left join
 sample s
 on s.dat = d.dat and s.name = c.name;
```

Comment: Good answer, except column names in result are not as requested. I forgot to get a unique set of dates in my answer ( now corrected ).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
select X.Date, X.Name, isnull(Y.C,0) as C
from
( select S.Date, company.Cname as Name from company, 
  (select Dat from sample group by Dat ) as S
) as X
left join sample as Y on Y.Name = X.Name  and Y.Dat = X.Dat
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot expect that output because your table lacks some data.
For instance, your Ford and Fiat does not exist on the sample, therefor will not give the desired ouput unless you use conditions.

For now, you should add

```
GROUP BY Date AND Cname
```

Comment: Hi Gark, Gordan's answer helped, cross joining works. Here is a DBFiddle for reference.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=253597931f0eec1fffba7bafd2cf42df